# Is GWT Mosaic still supported?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-mosaic

I am trying to support legacy Java web system which was initially developed using GWT 2.4 and GWT Mosaic v0.4.0. I tried to upgrade GWT version and project successfully compiled with GWT 2.5.0 but when I tried to compile it with GWT 2.6.0 I got an error with GWT Mosaic library. The reason was that GWT somewhat changed their object model concerning Element. I looked for newer versions of GWT Mosaic but found that last version deployed on the project site was dated 2010. Is this correct understanding that this project is dead and there is no way to use it with recent GWT versions?

Answer (score 1):

Project is dead.
But since it is open source you could always create a clone on GitHub and upgrade it to be 2.6.0 compatible. Some people would probably be grateful for that kind of action.